# ORA-01733 (Virtual column not allowed here) after database update

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

One of our databases has been updated from Oracle 9i to 11g. Since then one of our programs keeps getting said error when trying to update a column via a view. We updated the JDBC driver to 11g, too.

The view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UIV AS
SELECT
(SELECT FIR_KO_KREIS FROM FIRMA
WHERE FIR_KONZERN_NR = TRCO_KONZERN_NR
AND FIR_FIRMA_NR = TRCO_FIRMA_NR) UIVNFIRMA,
UIVAAENNKZ UIVAAENKZ,
UVVOL,
UVCLS,
UVID1,
UVID2,
UVID3,
UVID4,
UVID5,
UVID6,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVGJ)) UVGJ,
UVEINH,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW00)) UVW00,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW01)) UVW01,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW02)) UVW02,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW03)) UVW03,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW04)) UVW04,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW05)) UVW05,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW06)) UVW06,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW07)) UVW07,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW08)) UVW08,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW09)) UVW09,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW10)) UVW10,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW11)) UVW11,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW12)) UVW12,
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(UVW13)) UVW13,
NULL UVK01,
NULL UVK02,
NULL UVK03,
NULL UVK04,
NULL UVK05,
NULL UVK06,
NULL UVK07,
NULL UVK08,
NULL UVK09,
NULL UVK10,
NULL UVK11,
NULL UVK12,
NULL UVK13
FROM CO_BUCH;
```

Our program selects all records where `UIVAAENKZ` is 1. This column should be updated in a java `ResultSet` and set to 0.

On `resultSet.updateRow();` we get an exception with the oracle code 01733. Does anybody know if we can fix this? It worked fine with Oracle 9i.

---

EDIT: At first we write all the selected entries to a file. After that we rewind the result set (`extractedData`) and update the row:

```
extractedData.beforeFirst();
while (extractedData.next()) {
    extractedData.updateString("UIVAAENKZ", "0");
    extractedData.updateRow();
}
```

Please note that the column in the view is named slightly different than the one in the original table UIVAAENKZ UIVAAENNKZ. But as I said, this was no problem before.

The orginal table:

```
create table CO_BUCH
(
  uvvol              VARCHAR2(4),
  uvcls              VARCHAR2(4),
  uvid1              VARCHAR2(15),
  uvid2              VARCHAR2(15),
  uvid3              VARCHAR2(15),
  uvid4              VARCHAR2(15),
  uvid5              VARCHAR2(15),
  uvid6              VARCHAR2(15),
  fill001            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvgj               VARCHAR2(3),
  uveinh             VARCHAR2(4),
  fill002            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw00              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill003            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw01              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill004            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw02              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill005            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw03              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill006            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw04              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill007            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw05              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill008            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw06              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill009            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw07              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill010            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw08              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill011            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw09              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill012            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw10              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill013            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw11              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill014            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw12              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill015            VARCHAR2(1),
  uvw13              VARCHAR2(16),
  fill016            VARCHAR2(13),
  trco_konzern_nr    NUMBER,
  trco_firma_nr      NUMBER,
  trco_betrieb_nr    NUMBER,
  trco_tras_beleg_nr NUMBER,
  trco_senden_datum  DATE,
  trco_ausgabe       VARCHAR2(1000),
  uivaaennkz         VARCHAR2(1),
  uivaersben         VARCHAR2(10),
  uivdersdat         DATE,
  uivaaenben         VARCHAR2(10),
  uivdaendat         DATE,
  uivndsasta         NUMBER(2),
  uivnfirma          NUMBER
)
```

---

EDIT 2:

Ouptut of `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_DEFAULT, HIDDEN_COLUMN, VIRTUAL_COLUMN FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CO_BUCH' ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;`

```
UVVOL;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVCLS;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVID1;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVID2;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVID3;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVID4;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVID5;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVID6;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL001;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVGJ;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVEINH;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL002;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW00;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL003;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW01;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL004;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW02;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL005;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW03;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL006;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW04;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL007;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW05;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL008;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW06;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL009;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW07;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL010;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW08;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL011;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW09;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL012;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW10;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL013;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW11;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL014;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW12;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL015;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UVW13;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
FILL016;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
TRCO_KONZERN_NR;NUMBER;<null>;NO;NO
TRCO_FIRMA_NR;NUMBER;<null>;NO;NO
TRCO_BETRIEB_NR;NUMBER;<null>;NO;NO
TRCO_TRAS_BELEG_NR;NUMBER;<null>;NO;NO
TRCO_SENDEN_DATUM;DATE;<null>;NO;NO
TRCO_AUSGABE;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UIVAAENNKZ;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UIVAERSBEN;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UIVDERSDAT;DATE;<null>;NO;NO
UIVAAENBEN;VARCHAR2;<null>;NO;NO
UIVDAENDAT;DATE;<null>;NO;NO
UIVNDSASTA;NUMBER;<null>;NO;NO
UIVNFIRMA;NUMBER;<null>;NO;NO
```

Comment: Please add the code for the update statement as well.

Comment: @Codo Added the part that throws the exception.

Comment: What is the table definition for `CP_BUCH`? Is that a normal table; and is `UIVAAENNKZ` a normal column or a virtual column?

Comment: @AlexPoole added the create script; the column should be a normal column. The original table was created in 9i and they said: "we didn't change anything" as usual :)

Comment: What do you get by `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_DEFAULT, HIDDEN_COLUMN, VIRTUAL_COLUMN FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CP_BUCH' ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;`?

Comment: One remark about your business logic: As long as you are within one DB transaction, you can open a cursor (aka `ResultSet`) selecting all rows with `UIVAAENNKZ='1'` and then update your table to `SET  UIVAAENNKZ='0' WHERE UIVAAENNKZ='1'`. The transaction will make sure that both operations run on the same data. Move your file to its target location after successfully committing your transaction.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I will post the result on monday.

Comment: @MichaelSchaefers I will discuss that. Problem might be that we are extracting data from all sorts of database types (DB2 / MySql / Sql-Server / ...). Not sure if a transaction is handled like this everywhere.

Comment: @Moh-Aw: You said "At first we write all the selected entries to a file. After that we rewind the result set (extractedData) and update the row:". This will happen within one transaction. I just suggested that you do that differently, my intention was speeding up your task.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Added the output for your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have finally found a solution. While it might not be pretty, it works and it is simple.

The problem was the following column in the view which was selected from a different table:

```
(SELECT FIR_KO_KREIS FROM FIRMA
WHERE FIR_KONZERN_NR = TRCO_KONZERN_NR
AND FIR_FIRMA_NR = TRCO_FIRMA_NR) UIVNFIRMA
```

When we don't select this column during export everything works fine. Unfortunately we need this column, so we had to come up with a different solution.

An additional select around the whole selected data eliminates the problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UIV AS
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
(SELECT FIR_KO_KREIS FROM FIRMA
WHERE FIR_KONZERN_NR = TRCO_KONZERN_NR
AND FIR_FIRMA_NR = TRCO_FIRMA_NR) UIVNFIRMA,
UIVAAENNKZ UIVAAENKZ,
UVVOL,
UVCLS,
UVID1,
.
.
.
FROM CO_BUCH);
```